# Does "even more" make sense as an alternative to furthermore?

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

I'm helping an English-learner to practice for an English exam that includes an oral part. At one point she used "even more" in place of something like "furthermore". It sounded odd to me so I told her that she should use something like "also" or "furthermore" instead. She told me that an English teacher that she has been using told her to use "even more" because "furthermore" is too formal (the exam actually tests if you can use casual American English speech properly so you can be understood by other Americans). I later found out that the teacher is possibly British (based on their accent in a couple youtube videos I've watched). I looked up "even more" on Google and can't find any usage of the phrase that is equivalent to "furthermore".

Here are my questions:

1. Is this a British English expression?
2. Could this phrase be understood by Americans to mean the same as furthermore?

Comment: As an American, "even more" sounds a bit odd. While it may be understood, I don't think any American would use the phrase themselves. Your recommendations for alternatives are spot on if this is for an American oral exam. "Also" is a very casual and often used replacement for "furthermore". I don't think "furthermore" is too formal either.

Comment: I think "even more" works sometimes although it's a bit naked without something like "even more than that" . Depending on the situation there are lots of phrases that could stand in.  "To make things worse",  "If that weren't enough", "also" in many forms. Personally I find "furthermore" quite dated and stuffy and I think it might lose the confidence of many modern audiences outside of formal discussions(Including written observations).  "Furthermore" seems like lecturing or making a argument in favor of something possibly in dispute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I gave you a lot of good advice yesterday.  Today I have **even more**.

That would be an example of an informal use of "even more."

"Furthermore" is a bit stuffy.  Informal alternative:

> Mr. Johnson's advice is right on the mark.  *Furthermore*, it's free.
>
> Mr. Johnson's advice is right on the mark.  **What's more**, it's free.

(As far as I know, everything I wrote in this answer holds for British English as well as my native U.S. English.)